# Connecting DB on on Click event

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jsp, jdbc

I am designing a web application for which I want on an click event it retrieves data from DB and displays, I am designing in JSP, how do I connect using JDBC to DB on an onclick event. I have installed Oracle on localhost, Do I need to use any database server for this? If yes then which ?

Comment: Do you know how to access the database on a normal form submission. It is no different

Comment: No, I am new to this world, On submission, the event will be handled in Javascript and now how to connect DB from there?

Comment: I think you need to do some tutorials. Plenty of them on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like, you are new to using Oracle Database. Java applications require JDBC driver to connect to the Oracle Database. First, you must have either installed the Oracle Database or have access to a valid one. Then, you can follow simple steps to connect Java applications to the database. Try a simple java program [DataSourceSample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oracle-db-examples/blob/master/java/jdbc/ConnectionManagementSamples/DataSourceSample.java) to begin with. Refer to [JDBC Landing Page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/overview/index.html) for more resources